# Why is this always true?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with a random true or false.
It only does true or false each time depending on the code.
Does anyone have a solution to making it actually random?

```
int times;

for (left = 0; left < times; left++) {
        boolean result = (Math.random() < 0.5);
        if(result = true){
            System.out.println("Heads");
        }
        else if(result = false){
            System.out.println("Tails");
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

Comment: You need to use `if (result == true)`, or just `if (result)` instead. `if (result = true)` makes `result` true.

Comment: You should make your comparation using == operator. i.e. `result == true`

Comment: Both of your methods worked! Thanks

Comment: I am wondering what the purpose is for the "< 0.5" code snippet.  I'd get the result and then separate it out by greater than 0.5 vs <= 0.5, in if statements, and that should give you roughly a 50/50 split.  in the two if statements, use two equal signs "==" without the quotes.  When you use a single "=" it makes the left-hand value equal to the associated right hand value.

Comment: @K17, random is a half-open range that includes 0 but not 1. Hence 0.5 should be in the *top* half for a 50/50 split.

Comment: In short, `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment operator. This expression also returns value it assigns which is why we can create code like `a=b=c` which is same as `a=(b=1)` which assigns `1` to `b`, and returns that `1` so it can be also assigned to `c`. In your case you are handing `boolean` variables and you are assigning `true` to `result` and that `true` value is also passed to `if(...)` condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(result = true)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It actually *assigns* `true` to `result` and then uses that as the condition for the `if` statement. Hence the condition will *always* be true.

Use `==` instead or, since it's *already* a boolean value, just use (suitably renaming the variable from the way too generic `result`):

```
boolean FiftyPercentChance = (Math.random() < 0.5);
if (FiftyPercentChance) ...
```